# Require command in Yii PHP

Tags: php, yii, phpmailer

I'm using Yii framework for my web development.

I'm trying to make email cron job, for this i'm using PHPMailer.

here's my **config/console.php**

> ```
> > return array(
> >     'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
> >     'name'=>'My Console Application',
> > 
> >     // preloading 'log' component
> >     'preload'=>array('log'),
> >     'import'=>array(
> >             'application.modules.*',
> >             'application.extensions.*',
> >             'application.components.*',
> >             'application.models.*',
> >         ), ....
> ```

my **command/testCommand.php**

> ```
> class UptimeCheckerCommand extends CConsoleCommand{
>     public function run($args) { 
> .... 
> $warning->send(); 
> ....
> ```

my **component/Warning.php**

> ```
> ....
> require("/protected/extensions/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");
> ....
> ```

**Error Report:**

> ```
> PHP Error[2]: require(/protected/extensions/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php): fail
> ed to open stream: No such file or directory
> ```

I'm already testing it using controller to the component and it works perfectly fine. The error only happens when I'm trying to access it using **yiic test** command.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Does the same error occur when you change the require statement to `require("./protected/extensi...")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the quick reply.

I already tried a few suggestion from above.

The suggestion from **Andrey Shatilov** didn't work.

And for suggestion from **usman allam** and **mazraara** to change:

> require("/protected/extensions/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");

with

> Yii::import('application.extensions.PHPMailer.class.phpmailer.php');

can't work either because the file name has dot in it (class.phpmailer.php)

because of it, yii thought i request phpmailer.php in class folder instead of class.phpmailer.php

The code that works :

> **require("../protected/extensions/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");**

Don't know why this works because my testCommand.php in /protected/command/testCommand.php and my phpmailer file in /protected/extensions/PHPMailer/ but it works.

Answer (score 2):

```
'import'=>array(
   ...
   'application.extensions.PHPMailer.*',
   ...
)
```

and rename file **class.phpmailer.php** to **PHPMailer.php**

Importing a directory does not import any of its subdirectories.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
$mailer = Yii::import('application.extensions.phpmailer');
```

and then use **$mailer** to *send email*

Answer (score 1):

```
Yii::import('application.extensions.phpmailer');
```

Then you can create an object this way:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
```